# Summing over tanh squared

Tags: special-functions, mathematical-physics

I am working through [this](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0601062#:%7E:text=We%20find%20a%20one%2Dloop,generated%20by%20D%2Dbrane%20effects.) Physics paper. The authors perform a summation over modifed Bessel functions $K_{1}$ for small values of the argument, using the asymptotic relation $K_{1}(z) \approx \frac{1}{z}$ for $z << 1$.
$$ \sum_{n = -\infty}^{+\infty} \frac{2}{\pi} \frac{b \sinh^{4}(\pi Q \ell_{S} n / 2)}{[2 \sinh^{2}(\pi Q \ell_{S} n) \xi^{+} \xi^{-}]^{1/2}}  K_{1}\Big(\sqrt{8b^{2} \sinh^{2}(\pi Q \ell_{S} n) \xi^{+} \xi^{-}}\Big)$$
$$ \approx \frac{1}{8 \pi \xi^{+} \xi^{-}} \sum_{n} \tanh^{2}(\pi Q \ell_{s}n/2)$$
$$ \approx  \frac{1}{8 \pi^{2}Q \ell_{s} \xi^{+}\xi^{-}}\log(2 b^{2} \xi^{+}\xi^{-})$$My question is: How is the last step accomplished i.e. getting from $\sum \tanh^{2}$ to $\log$? The authors claim that the summation is performed over only those values of $n$ for which the argument of the modified Bessel function $K_{1} $ is less than 1.

Thank you.

Comment: Please read this on *How to ask a good question*:  https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/31696/210401

Comment: @DavidG.Stork I understand that all the constants might look unnecessary, but i do not know that right now. In particular, I'm confused about why the $\xi^{+} \xi^{-}$ dependence is transfered to the $\log$.

Comment: You *do* know that constants are constants and irrelevant to the problem, though.